# How to tail/stream syslog in Nixos

Tags: syslog, tail, nix, nixos

I was looking here:
https://github.com/NixOS/nixos/blob/master/modules/services/logging/syslogd.nix

I tried a simple:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

but that yields:

> tail: cannot open '/var/log/syslog' for reading: No such file or
>   directory

Answer (score 5):

Did you enable syslogd? By default, system logging is done by journald.

#### Assuming you enabled syslogd

Look at the default configuration in [the syslogd service definition](https://github.com/NixOS/nixos/blob/master/modules/services/logging/syslogd.nix) to see where it logs. `/var/log/syslog` is currently not there or in the manpage.

#### Assuming journald

Use

```
journalctl -f
```